# checkstyle regex is not working

Tags: java, regex, checkstyle

This regex should find java classes witch no '@Configuration' word and more than one '@Inject' word. In java Matcher it works, but not in checkstyle.

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value="(?s)((?!@Configuration).)*@Inject.*@Inject.*"/>
</module>
```

In this example result is false, but if u delete `@Configuration` from target text then result is true - good. Checkstyle always produces true.

[example regex test](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/regex/b489c8f5-7644-4489-b90d-216ec6a5904b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegexpMulitiline` check is based on [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--), see [`checks/regexp/MultilineDetector.java#L95`](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/77dc350b506821204e8f41854fb81773b2e822db/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/regexp/MultilineDetector.java#L95).

And indeed your example shows that there is `Find` result (there is no `Match` though). You need to accommodate your pattern to return nothing also for `Find`.